# Replacing differently formatted IP addresses within a file with Bash?

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, replace, ip

**Context:**
I have several `.properties` files that contain IP addresses within them of the form:

```sh
    advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-68-51-0-82.ec2.internal:9092
    advertised.host.name=ip-68-51-0-82.ec2.internal
```

*(The IP addresses have been randomized for anonymity)*

**Solution in Theory:** I am trying to automatically replace the mentioned IP addresses within the `.properties` file with the result of the bash command `hostname -i` from within a bash script (as opposed to manually editing the IP's in VIM).

**Problem:** `hostname -i` returns the IP address I need, but in a different format. It returns `62.57.0.85` which is in dot notation rather than dash notation.

**Goal:** To change the text of the file to now read:

```
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal:9092
advertised.host.name=ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal
```

How would I do this? Would I use something like `sed`?

**UPDATE (7/6/2021 at 19:06):** After looking at the answer and identifying further constraints on the problem, here is the code that worked for me:

`sed -i "s|68-51-0-82|$(hostname -i | tr . -)|g" server.properties`

To further elaborate, I am able to hardcode the IP I wish to replace because I know that it will always be the same. If you don't, and need to pattern match against any potential IP address, refer to the original answer to this question.

As for the usage of `tr`, it's a quick and easy way to convert the format of the hostname (which is in dot notation by default) to dash notation. I then use the output of the `tr` command directly in the `sed` command via a `$` variable

Comment: `tr` would be simpler.

Comment: Could you expand on that? I'm a beginner to bash, so how would I pass the hostname to tr?

Comment: `hostname -i | tr . _`

Comment: Perfect, and once that's done, how would I similarly grep that result into a specific file that replaces 68-51-0-82 with 62-57-0-85?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED** based on further comments/clarifications by OP:

```
$ oldip='68-51-0-82'                        # OP knows in advance the IP that needs to be replaced in the file
$ newip='62-57-0-85'                        # OP has already swapped out periods for hyphens
$ sed "s/${oldip}/${newip}/g" .properties
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal:9092
advertised.host.name=ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal
```

If OP knows `oldip` will **ALWAYS** be the same (ie, `68-51-0-82`) then this could be hardcoded into the `sed` call like such:

```
$ sed "s/68-51-0-82/${newip}/g" .properties
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal:9092
advertised.host.name=ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal
```

---

---

Assumptions:

- on my VM `hostname -i` ==> `fe80::5454:7ccf:aa17:f765%13 10.8.1.6 192.168.1.4` ... so I'm assuming OP has already parsed the new ip address into a variable (eg, `newip`)
- all ip addresses in the file match the format of what OP's posted, namely `<stuff>.ip-n1-n2-n3-n4.<stuff>`)

One idea using `sed`:

```
$ cat .properties
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-68-51-0-82.ec2.internal:9092
advertised.host.name=ip-68-51-0-82.ec2.internal

$ newip='62.57.0.85'

$ sed "s/ip-[^\.]+\./ip-${newip//./-}\./" .properties
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal:9092
advertised.host.name=ip-62-57-0-85.ec2.internal
```

Where:

- `ip-[^\.]+\.` - match the string `ip-` + `<everything that's not a period>` + a literal period (`.`)
- `ip-${newip//./-}\.` - replace with string `ip-` + our variable (periods replaced with hyphens) + a literal period (`.`)

If OP is looking to overwrite `.properties`, and has verified this `sed` command does what's expected, the `-i` flag can be added to tell `sed` to overwrite the input file (ie, `.properties`).

Comment: As pointed out in the comments above, I can simplify this by getting the target ip into the dash format via `hostname -i | tr . -`. If I store that as a variable instead, would the sed code now read `sed "s/ip-[^\.]+\./ip-${newip}\./" .properties`?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally yes, that looks right; are you getting a 'wrong' answer with your proposed `sed` code? (if so, please update the question with your `sed` attempt and the 'wrong' output you're getting); regards

Comment: Actually I just realized I could further simplify the code. The file I am trying to replace will actually always have the same initial IP address. (I.e.  I am ALWAYS looking to replace ip-68-51-0-82 with newip) So how would I hardcode that inital IP into the sed command?

Comment: for the benefit of others who stumble across this Q&A ... I'd suggest updating the question with all of your latest comments and findings; not everyone is going to spend the time reading through comments trying to piece together the big(ger) picture; in the meantime I'll update the answer with what I think you're suggesting ....

Comment: Good idea, I'll definitely do that